# Call a function when any anchor tag inside a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu like

```
<div class="nav_bar" style="background: url(../images/nav.jpg) repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;">
            <div id="navID" class="ddsmoothmenu">
                <ul id='Ul2'>
                            <li id='Li6'><a href="inner.php" title="Home">Home </a>  
                            </li>
                  </ul>
               <ul id='Ul4' >
               <li id='Li1' ><a href="#" title="Master">Car </a>    
                <ul>
                    <li id='Li10'><a href="#" title="Plan Type">Fuel</a>
                    <ul>                                  
                        <li id='Li10' ><a href="Petrol.php" title="Petrol">Petrol  </a> </li>
                        <li id='Li10' ><a href="Diesel.php" title="Diesel">Diesel  </a></li>                                   </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
                  </li>

              </div>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to call a event or a function for click in any anchor tag within the div nav_bar?
I have tried

```
$(".nav_bar #navID").click(function(e) {
    alert("hai");
     });
```

but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code should work as is, so perhaps you're missing the jQuery library, or perhaps you need to wrap the call in `$(function () {\* code here*\ })`

Comment: @Faust seems like OP will navigate away before the handler fires.

Comment: can i know the reason for negative vote

Comment: This concept is covered extensively in the jQuery docs; that's why I personally downvoted.

Comment: @Mathletics I may missed it,thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Mathletics: true enough. It needs `e.preventDefault()` too.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Just add `a` to the selector to select the anchor tags.

```
$("#navID a").click(function(e) {
    alert("hai");
});
```

As it looks like all of the anchor tags are inside the div with the ID `navID` you can just use that as the parent selector. It is faster to select using an ID than it is using a class.

Comment: mine is faster :-p (kidding, it makes no difference at this scale obvs)

Comment: Didn't the OP ask about the nav_bar?  This is for the navId div.

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre They did, but the `#navID` div contains all of the anchor tags and has an ID so it makes sense to select that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your nav_bar is a class, not an ID, you should do this:

```
$('.nav_bar a').click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gS3KJ/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a sufficiently modern version of jQuery:

```
$('.nav_bar').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$("#nav_bar a").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("hai");
    return false;
});
```